# Opening links in the browser in PhoneGap (with a non-local index.html root)

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, uiwebview, webview

I've seen a few different discussions on how to open links in the browser instead of the WebView like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14070841/phonegap-open-link-in-browser) and [Phonegap's own documentation](https://build.phonegap.com/blog/access-tags). I'm having problems getting either of those two to work, though, and I'm wondering if it's because I'm loading a URL other than a local `index.html` file. Here's my setup.

I'm loading a URL `www.example.com`. I want all URLs that are `www.non-example.com` to open in  the browser, while keeping all sub-URLs loading in my WebView. I've edited `cordova.xml` to have

```
<access origin="http://www.example.com"/>
```

but when I put a URL with

```
<a href="http://www.non-example.com" target="_blank">Foo</a>
```

and click it in my Android device, it just opens it in the WebView rather than the browser. I don't know if this is relevant, but I updated my PhoneGap to 2.2 with this release, and added a `config.xml` at the same level as my `index.html` (though I'm not sure it's being used, because I didn't recreate my Android project from scratch). So my questions boil down to these:

1) How do I ensure URLs are opening in the browser if I'm using a non-local index.html?

2) How do I know if my `config.xml` file is being used?

Answer (score 0):

I just tried what you described and it works fine with Cordova 2.3.

ad 1)

Did you make sure that you removed other conflicting access rules, i.e. the default rule (access origin=".*") - The loosest rule wins.

ad 2)

Clean your project before rebuilding it to ensure the updated config.xml gets used.

If you want to enforce an exact behavior you could always use a plugin and native code, although for opening the browser this might be an overkill.

Comment: Yeah, I don't have any other rules in the access. Did you load it with a non-local index.html? :) I keep wondering if that's causing problems.

Comment: @Waynn - the link I tried was to a non-local (external) website.

Comment: Hm, I just tested it on Cordova 2.5 and I can't seem to get it to work. The only non-commented rules I have on `config.xml` are `<access origin="http://foo.example.com"/>` and <content src="http://foo.example.com" />. But when I have a link to `amazon.com`, it still opens it in the WebView as opposed to browser.

Answer (score 0):

There seem's to be an accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14070841/phonegap-open-link-in-browser).  The gist looks like you can call the navigator object and tell it to open a link, passing a parameter of {external: true}.  I haven't tested it though, good luck!

Comment: Yeah, I know you can use the navigator object, but PhoneGap's documentation (https://build.phonegap.com/blog/access-tags) implies that you can just use _target="blank" and it should work.

Comment: Hmm.  The link says "we've tried to mitigate this by setting the default whitelist on each platform that supports one (Android, iOS, and BlackBerry) to a wildcard.".  Going to ask the obvious question: the wildcard's not in your config.xml anymore, is it?  

The apk is just a jar file.  You can 
    java jar -xf <file>.apk
and check in the res directory to see if the config.xml is actually your xml file.

Comment: Any update on whether or not the APK indeed has your custom config.xml in it or not?

Comment: I used `jar -xf <file>.apk` and it seems to be using the res/xml/config.xml that's originally there. If I have config.xml defined in both res/xml and in assets/www, are they both used? Or does one override the other?

Comment: When you compile a PG application locally, you put config.xml into res/xml.  I would think that you put config.xml into the assets/www folder when using PGBuild because you don't really have access to any of the native project when you upload a website. My hunch would be that assets/www/config.xml is moved to res/xml/config.xml to be consistent across local and PGBuild compilations.  Based on that, I think the default config.xml is being picked up by the application and that's causing the problem.