# Phonegap submit external browser

Tags: cordova

I'm having a problem with phonegap (2.5.0 version) to open a form submit on the external web browser on Android and iPhone. I want to submit a form like this:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form method="POST" target="_blank" action="https://externalDomain.com">
            <input type="text" name="username"/>
            <input type="text" name="password/>
            <input type="submit" value="accept"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

So the execution of this script happens in a file stored on the device lets say "index.html", and I want the submit to open on the browser, because I need the user to fill a payment processor form on "externalDomian.com".

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14070841/phonegap-open-link-in-browser

Comment: Did you manage to fix this? I am having the same issue.