# html 5 android native app link target new window

Tags: android, html, jquery-mobile, hyperlink

i am developing HTML5 android native app using Jquery mobile framework...
at last for build my app i used Phonegap build features,  its working great,

My question is i had added some links inside my application, for example:

```
<a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">tap here</a>
```

when i tap this link, this link page opening same window... i had added `target _blank` also, but still its working same page, i need when we tap this link open a new window or open default browser that installed my android device.

Comment: This question looks like it has some answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14070841/phonegap-open-link-in-browser

Comment: Try `data-rel=external`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at last i have find out what i am really looking answer for...

add this code `<access origin="http://yourdomain.com" onlyInBrowser="true" />` to `config.xml`

see this link http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/make_links_use_external_broswer_consistently